# non-object error on Doctrine 2 entity manager object

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to learn the zend framework by reading through a book. So far all the code in it has worked, but now I'm having trouble authenticating users. The book suggests doing this through an action helper and doctrine 2's entity managers.

here's the code i'm using for this

my authenticate helper class...

```
public function init()
{           

  // Initialize the errors array
  Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->errors = array();
  $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
  $em = $this->getActionController()->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('entityManager');    
  if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $identity = $auth->getIdentity();

    if (isset($identity)) {     
      $user = $em->getRepository('Entities\User')->findOneByEmail($identity);
      Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->user = $user;                   
    }
  }
}
```

the entity repository function...

```
public function findOneByEmail($email)
{

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;

$rsm->addEntityResult('Entities\User', 'a');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'email', 'email');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'fname', 'fname');

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery(
  'SELECT a.id, a.fname, a.email FROM users a 
     WHERE a.email = :email',
  $rsm
);

$query->setParameter('email', $email);
return $query->getResult();
```

}

On the page view, i'm using the following code to check that the user is logged in:

```
<?php 
if($this->user){ 
    ?>Welcome back, <a href="/user/"><?php echo $this->user->fname; ?></a> &bull; <a href="/user/logout/">Logout</a><?php 
} ?>
```

the if condition passes when i'm logged in, but it won't print the user's name.

here's the error message I get on it:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dev.test.com\application\views\scripts\user\index.phtml on line 3
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem is here:

```
if (isset($identity)) {     
    $user = $em->getRepository('Entities\User')->findOneByEmail($identity);
    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->user = $user;                   
}
```

It looks like findOneByEmail expects the email address as the parameter but the whole identity object is being passed.

That probably causes `return $query->getResult();` to return null or false so `$view->user` is not an object and has no property fname.

I think in findOneByEmail you need to do something like `$user = $em->getRepository('Entities\User')->findOneByEmail($identity->email);` where `$identity->email` is the property that contains the email address.

Comment: I double checked on that. $identity is a string that's just the email address.

Comment: Ok, in that case, try a `var_export` on the return value from the function to make sure `$query->getResult();` is returning the correct data.

Comment: the var_export of $user from the helper: array ( 0 => Entities\User::__set_state(array( 'id' => 1, 'fname' => 'Liz', 'lname' => NULL, 'email' => 'liz@test.com', 'password' => NULL, 'phone' => NULL, 'active' => NULL, 'role' => NULL, 'created' => NULL, 'updated' => NULL, 'inactive' => NULL, )), )

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have an array, you could change the findOneByEmail function to do this: `$result = $query->getResult();  if (sizeof($result) == 0) { return false; } else { return $result[0]; }`

Comment: Progress! the non-object error went away. Now I'm getting 'Fatal error: cannot access private property entities\user::$fname in ....applications\views\scripts\user\index.phtml'

Comment: Do you have a getter you can call on the result, like `$user->getFname()`?

Comment: I do but that gives me an undefined property error on Entities\User::$getFirstname

Comment: Undefined property may mean that the getter is not grabbing the right property from the object.  That is you have `private $_fName;` but maybe it is trying to return `$this->_firstName` instead.

Comment: I forgot the parentheses at the end of the call. So it works like this: $this->user->getFirstname();  Thank you so much for help!  This has been driving me crazy all afternoon!